# Is this type of promise nesting good practice?

Tags: javascript, promise, nested

I just wanted to know if it is considered good practice to nest promises like in this example, or is there better alternatives ?

```
getDatabaseModel.searchId(idNoms).then(function([noms, elements]) {
        getDatabaseModel.getLocalisations().then(function(localisations){
            getDatabaseModel.getStates().then(function(states){
                //Some code
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: async await is what you want

Comment: You're reinventing callback hell, which is what promises were designed to avoid. Return a new promise into the chain: `a.b().then(function (args) { return a.c(); }).then(function (args) { return a.d(); }).then(...)`

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like your calls really depend on each other, so you might want to fire them all in parallel, and accumulate the results: `Promise.all([a.b(), a.c(), a.d()]).then(function ([b, c, d]) { ... })`.

Comment: [Aren't promises just callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22539815)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, your promises are independent. So you should use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to make it run parallel with the highest performance.

> The Promise.all() method takes an iterable of promises as an input,
> and returns a single Promise that resolves to an array of the results
> of the input promises

```
var searchById = getDatabaseModel.searchId(idNoms);
var getLocalisations = getDatabaseModel.getLocalisations();
var getStates = getDatabaseModel.getStates();

var result = Promise.all([searchById, getLocalisations, getStates]);
result.then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

For example, Let's say each promise takes 1s - So it should be 3s in total, But with `Promise.all`, actually it just takes 1s in total.

```js
var tick = Date.now();
const log = (v) => console.log(`${v} \n Elapsed: ${Date.now() - tick}`);

log("Staring... ");
var fetchData = (name, ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(name), ms));
var result = Promise.all(
            [
              fetchData("searchById", 1000), 
              fetchData("getLocalisations", 1000),
              fetchData("getStates", 1000)
            ]);
result.then((values) => {
  log("Complete...");
  console.log(values);
});
```

Besides, If you're concern about [asyn/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) with more elegant/concise/read it like sync code, then `await` keyword much says the code should **wait until the async request is finished and then afterward it'll execute the next thing**. While those promises are independent. So `promise.all` is better than in your case.

```js
var tick = Date.now();
const log = (v) => console.log(`${v} \n Elapsed: ${Date.now() - tick}`);

var fetchData = (name, ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(name), ms));
Run();

async function Run(){
  log("Staring... ");
  
  var a = await fetchData("searchById", 1000);
  var b = await fetchData("getLocalisations", 1000);
  var c = await fetchData("getStates", 1000);
  
  log("Complete...");
  console.log([a, b, c]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Promises were made to avoid callback hell, but they are not too good at it too. People like promises until they find async/await. The exact same code can be re-written in async/await as

```
async getModel(idNoms){
  const [noms, elements] = await getDatabaseModel.searchId(idNoms);
  const localisations = await getDatabaseModel.getLocalisations();
  const state = await getDatabaseModel.getStates():
  // do something using localisations & state, it'll work

}

getModel(idNoms);
```

Learn async/await [here](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Comment: `await` keyword much says the code should wait until the async request is finished and then afterwards it'll execute the next thing. While those promises are indepentent. So `promise.all` is better than :)

Comment: I understand what you mean and it's not that I am not aware of Promise.all, going by OP's code, I do see they are not dependent on each other, but I also noted that OP has nested them coz of some reason instead, otherwise he would have not nested them and called 3 promises serially and hence awaiting, I put the results into variables too. @Phong

Comment: Seems like Promise.all() was the best way in my case, but i'm sure your example will be helpful in the future !

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 2):

IMO it's a little hard to read and understand. Compare with this:

```js
getDatabaseModel.searchId(idNoms)
    .then(([noms, elements]) => getDatabaseModel.getLocalisations())
    .then(localization => getDatabaseModel.getStates());
```

As @deceze pointed out there are two things to note:

- These functions are called **serially**
- They don't seem to depend on each other as the `noms`, `elements` and `localization` are not used at all.

With `Promise.all` you can mix and match however you want:

```js
// Call `searchId` and `getState` at the same time
// Call `getLocalisations` after `searchId` is done
// wait for all to finish
Promise.all([
  getDatabaseModel.searchId(idNoms).then(([noms, elements]) => getDatabaseModel.getLocalisations()),
  getDatabaseModel.getStates()
]).then(([result1, result2]) => console.log('done'));


// Call all 3 at the same time
// wait for all to finish
Promise.all([
  getDatabaseModel.searchId(idNoms),
  getDatabaseModel.getLocalisations(),
  getDatabaseModel.getStates(),
]).then(([result1, result2, result3]) => console.log('done'));
```